# Exclude posts from the_post_navigation() by category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the `the_post_navigation()` function in WordPress like this:

```
<?php the_post_navigation( array(
    'prev_text' => __( 'Previous item'),
    'next_text' => __( 'Next item'),
)); ?>
```

This navigation goes through all my posts, but I want to exclude the posts that contain the category 'footer'. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to let the page redirects itself when the single.php goes to a post with the category 'footer':

```
 if(in_category('footer')){
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    $location = get_permalink( $next_post->ID );
    wp_redirect( $location );
    exit;
 } else {}
```

(Works only when places above `get_header();`.
Not the most beautiful solution, but it works (only for next post unfortunately)

Comment: $prevPost = get_adjacent_post(false,'30,31,32,410',true); check this

Comment: Well, getting the previous post is not the problem. The problem is that this function initializes when the page is loaded. I have to find a way that it recognizes when it has to go to the previous post, and when it has to go to the next post.